# C++ Variable Type Selection at Runtime

Tags: c++

I am upgrading an old application which was written for a specific hardware interface.  I now need to add support for a modern hardware to the existing application.

To do this, I would like to create a class for each hardware type, and assign a variable to one type or the other whenever the user selects which hardware is in their system.

For example:

Class `HardwareType1` and Class `HardwareType2` both exist having the same member functions.

```
object HW;  
if (userHwType = 1)  
    // initialize HW as a HardwareType1 class
}  
else{  
    // initialize HW as a HardwareType2 class  
}
```

Now I can use `HW.doSomething()` throughout my code without a conditional for hardware type every time I interact with the hardware.

I'm sure this is pretty basic but to be honest I don't even know what this is called or what terms to search on for this one.

Thanks!

Comment: You are looking for inheritance, from the _Object Oriented Programming_ paradigm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create an an abstract base class, and derive two concrete classes from it: one implementing type1 and the other implementing type2:

```
class Hardware
{
public:
    virtual ~Hardware() {};
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class Hardware1: public Hardware
{
public:
    void doSomething() { // hardware type1 stuff. }
};


class Hardware2: public Hardware
{
public:
    void doSomething() { // hardware type2 stuff. }
};
```

Then create the necessary instance:

```
std::unique_ptr<Hardware> hardware(1 == userHwType ? new Hardware1() : 
                                                     new Hardware2());

hardware->doSomething();
```

---

If you compiler does not support C++11 then [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) will not be available to you. An alternative smart pointer would [`boost::scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) (or [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)).

Answer (score 3):

Use polymorphism with a common abstract base class, like this:

```
class HardwareBase
{
public:
    virtual void Open() = 0;
    virtual void Close() = 0;
    virtual ~HardwareBase() {};
};
```

Then derive your concrete hardware types:

```
class HardwareType1 : public HardwareBase
{
public:
    virtual void Open() {...}
    virtual void Close() {...}
};
```

And select the required hardware instance:

```
std::unique_ptr<HardwareBase> hw;  
if (userHwType == 1)  
    hw.reset(new HardwareType1());
else
    hw.reset(new HardwareType2());

// And use it like this:
hw->Open();
```

Note that you now need a pointer to the selected object instance.
Use a unique_ptr to automatically delete it on exit.

Answer (score 1):

The term to search for is *polymorphism*; that's the general term for interacting with different types through a common interface.

In C++, if you need to select behaviour at runtime, the usual approach is to define an *abstract interface*, which acts as a *base class* for your *concrete types*, using *virtual functions* - the function to call is chosen at runtime depending on the true type of the object.

```
// Abstract interface
class Hardware {
public:
    virtual ~Hardware() {}  // needed to safely delete objects

    virtual void doSomething() = 0;  // must be implemented by each concrete type
};

// One concrete type
class HardwareType1 : public Hardware
{
    HardwareType1() { /* initialise */ }
    void doSomething() { /* implementation for this type of hardware */ }
};

// Another concrete type
class HardwareType2 : public Hardware
{
    HardwareType2() { /* initialise */ }
    void doSomething() { /* implementation for this type of hardware */ }
};
```

Now you can choose which to create, and then interact using the abstract interface:

```
// Create the correct type, depending on user input
std::unique_ptr<Hardware> hw
    ((userHwType == 1) ? new HardwareType1 : new HardwareType2);

// Do the right thing depending on the type
hw->doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search for factory method. That is the name of the pattern you are trying to implement